# connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec returns nothing

Tags: python, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I want to login into a POD and run few commands and basically capture output.
But this is returning nothing.

P.S. podname, namespace, containername are just examples. In my examples, am passing real values.
Also, These PODs are deployed in AWS Cluster

```
def runCommand(self, command, podname, namespace,servicename ):
            resp = stream(self.api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
                  podname,
                  namespace,
                  command=command,
                  container= servicename,
                  stderr=True, stdin=False,
                  stdout=True, tty=False,
                  _preload_content=False)
            
            return resp.read_stdout()

runCommand(['ls'], 'podname','namespace', 'containername')
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.

Reason - preload content is present. It is set to true by default. If you make it false, api response will not be read.

Found below chunk in the documentation:

_preload_content: if False, the urllib3.HTTPResponse object will
be returned without reading/decoding response
data. Default is True.